# Ajax Request New XML HTTP Request does not work from mobile (m) url

Tags: javascript, ajax, mobile, request

I have a problem on my website. I run my ajax script from the www site. everything works.
I'm running the same script from the m (mobile) site and nothing happens.

This is the setup of my ajax request.

```
function ajaxfunc(){


    
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I opened the site on my PC. both the www and m version.
I also already checked all included files for errors.
It simply won't use my ajax function.